# span tag binding issues with angular interpolation

Tags: html, css, angular, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to use span tag inside{{}}with condition

`<label class="control-label label-floating">{{labelEnglish  =='Name'?labelEnglish + '<span style="color:red">*</span>' : labelEnglish}} </label>`

as you can see I want to check if labelEnglish equal to Name it should bind red star to it otherwise just print the value

I tried to use ng-if `<span ng-if="labelEnglish == 'Name'" style="color:red">*</span>` within span and this is what is got 
[image]

I assigned a labelEnglish value to Name to display it in Name input and owner to owner input and so on `<name  name="dName" labelEnglish="Name" labelArabic="الاسم"  required CurrentLanguageRequired="true"></name>`
how can i chick labelEnglish vlaue in this case?

Comment: is this angularjs or angular? Please tag your question accordingly.

Comment: `angularjs` refers to version 1.x.x whereas `angular` refers to version 2+. If you hover over the tags you can see info :)

Comment: I deleted the question about the difference between angular and angularjs accidentally :)  thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add DOM by this way.

Use `ng-if` / `ng-show`

```
<label class="control-label label-floating">
   {{labelEnglish}}
   <span ng-if="labelEnglish == 'Name'" style="color:red">*</span>         
</label>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pggfqc09/)

Comment: it's not checking lableEnglih value hence it will print the star with all input using labelEnglish like phone, city etc